# Criando objetos com rpy2

Tags: python, r

Existem duas maneiras de criar objetos R usando rpy2?

Tenho um exemplo:

```
import rpy2.robjects as robjects  

# Criando um objeto R a partir do Python  
robjects.r('''  
rfunc <- function() {  
print("ola")  
}  
''')  

# Imprimindo a definição da função  
r_func = robjects.globalenv['rfunc']  

#imprime a função  
r_func
```

Parece-me que tem outra forma:

```
pi = robjects.r['pi']
```

Mas daqui em diante não consegui fazer um exemplo completo.

Existem realmente duas maneiras de criar objeto R no python?